# why doesn't dereferencing a polymorphic pointer call derived type argument in a function?

Tags: c++

i do not understand why this behavior occurs:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void enablePolymorphism();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void enablePolymorphism();
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    void enablePolymorphism();
};

void callMe(Base base)
{
     printf("base");
}

void callMe(Derived derived)
{
     printf("derived");
}

void callMe(Derived2 derived2)
{
     printf("derived2");
}

int main()
{
    Base* pointer = new Derived();
    Base* pointer2 = new Derived2();
    callMe(*pointer);
    callMe(*pointer2);
    return 0;
}
```

this is what i actually want my code to do and i want the method callMe() to be outside the classes therefore i cannot use virtual functions, i want at run-time for the program to call callMe(Derived derived) when i do callMe(*pointer) and callMe(Derived2 derived2) when i do callMe(*pointer2) for which the output would be derivedderived2 but that's not what happens, at compile-time pointer and pointer2 are assumed to be of Base class when dereferenced so the callMe(Base base) is called instead and the output is basebase. How do i achieve the output i want? thank you.

Comment: why should it call `callMe(Derived)` if the argument is `Base*`?

Comment: You should perhaps first try to understand the concept of polymorphism, before you are using it.

Comment: Do you maybe want double dispatch? There are quite some library solutions for this aronud, but C++ doesnt have native support

Comment: but it is derefenced as in the actual type is of Derived type but as the answers indicate, this is decided at compile time and i need it to be at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

```
void callMe(A);
void callMe(B);

A*ptr;
callMe(*ptr);  // guess which of the above is called?
```

this has nothing to do with polymorphism, but is simple overloading resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Runtime polymorphism applies only to *member* functions that are marked with the `virtual` keyword (or that override a `virtual` member function):

```
virtual void callMe();
```

For a non-member function, or a non-virtual member function, the appropriate overload is selected at compile time based on the declared type (not the runtime type) of the argument(s).

Comment: how do i make it based on the runtime type and i can't cast because i have multiple derived objects and i want it to automatically figure out which object it points to

Comment: @user1477 use a `virtual` member function.

Comment: but that makes me put the function in the classes i want to access them outside like i did in the example

Answer (score 2):

The only thing the compiler sees is that the expression `*pointer` is of type `Base&` and therefore succeeds into choosing the correct overload `callMe(Base)` for the function.

In your case, you can use a polymorphic function instead:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void callMe() { std::cout << "called base"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void callMe() { std::cout << "called derived"; }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> pointer(new Derived());
    pointer->callMe();
    return 0;
}
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29d4e7497352b69b) is the live example.

Comment: is there a way to do this then like an automatic casting that automatically casts the pointer to Base to a pointer to Derived? this is useful if i have multiple derived objects and i want it to automatically downcast to the appropriate object pointer

Comment: I'm sure you can use `dynamic_cast` to cast a `Base*` to `Derived*`, but you might want to consider using a polymorphic function instead of a free function.

Comment: i cant cast Base* to Derived* because i have multiple derived objects for example Derived1 and Derived2 i do not know at compile time which one of the 2 the Base* is pointing to so i can't cast it, i need it to automatically cast it

Comment: @user1477, `dynamic_cast` can fail. You can try by checking if the result of `dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(ptr)` is `nullptr` (`0`).

Comment: no you are not understanding what i meant i have Base* pointer = new Derived1(); but i cannot know at compile time that it is Derived1() or Derived2() which is why i can't cast it to begin with